# VB.NET access database, how to create number field

Tags: vb.net

How do I create a number field in access database using vb.net?

For example if I have this:

```
"CREATE TABLE [" & username_v.Text & "] ([test] TEXT(100))"
```

It creates my "test" as a TEXT field. How do I create a number field? Have tried NUMBER, INT, INTEGER and some others, but I get a syntax error...

How tried google, but can't find my answar...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE " & username_v.Text & " ([Test] TEXT(100));
```

This is the syntax for `MS ACCESS`. Wrap the syntax with "" when executeing from a `VB.NET` application

```
"CREATE TABLE " & username_v.Text & " ([Test] TEXT(100));"
```

Here is a example of different datatypes. Its recommended to Always use a Primary Key.

```
CREATE TABLE " & username_v.Text & "
(
    [ID] AUTOINCREMENT,
    [Test] TEXT(100),
    [Integerfield] INTEGER,
    [DateDatypeField] DATETIME,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NUMBER`, although you mentioned already number and add the `;` at the end to be safe, like:

```
"CREATE TABLE [" & username_v.Text & "] ([test] TEXT(100), [ID] Number);"
```

Or INTEGER if you want an integer:

```
"CREATE TABLE [" & username_v.Text & "] ([test] TEXT(100), [ID] Integer);"
```

And if you want a primary key for that, you could do like this:

```
"CREATE TABLE [" & username_v.Text & "] ([ID] Integer NOT NULL, [test] TEXT(100), Primary Key([ID]) );"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
CREATE TABLE " & username_v.Text & " ([Test] TEXT(100), Total SHORT);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE " & username_v.Text & " ([Test] TEXT(100), Total LONG);
```

see for other Access Data Types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx